# Grafana filtering Thanos store labels| Grafana Promtheus Thanos

Tags: prometheus, grafana, thanos

I was wondering is there any way to filter by Thanos store in `Thanos+prometheus+Grafana` cluster. I am trying to query from Grafana dashboard to get results from exactly one store (we have 3).
Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by using following query:
`prometheus_engine_queries`
with following filter:

```
/.*env=\"(.*)\",instance/
```

`env` - this is from `-set storeGateway.additionalLabels.env` and it is added to every metrics

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I am new in PromQL and Grafana could you please explain it in more detail? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should modify configs so thanos sidecars would have Announced LabelSets based on source. This should add those labels to every metric you store in thanos. Later just modify dashboards to use those labels as variables for selection and in expressions

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue.
I wasn't able to filter on any of my `externalLabels` in Grafana PromQL queries :

```yaml
prometheus:
  externalLabels:
    cluster: my_cluster
```

My misstake was that I configured the data source wrong in Grafana. I used `prometheus-operated` instead of the actual query service :

```
http://thanos-query:9090
```